# How to open port 443 on Mac 10.7.5?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, macos

Hi I'm receiving an SSL issue on my rails app on my local server:

```
An error occurred during a connection to localhost:3000.

SSL received a record that exceeded the maximum permissible length.

(Error code: ssl_error_rx_record_too_long)
```

and was told that opening port 443 would fix the problem. I've looked around everywhere but there doesn't seem to be an answer. Could someone go through the process of how I would open port 443?

Comment: We'd really need a lot more info to be much help here. What does port 443 have to do with your service on port 3000? Is port 443 closed because nothing's running on it, or because it's being blocked by a firewall? If nothing's running, what needs to be running (more specific than "https", please)? If a firewall is blocking it, which firewall and what network source does it need to be reachable from? Finally, are you running OS X Server, plain OS X, or plain OS X with something like MAMP on top of it?

Answer (score 1):

So, someone is advising you to open that port in your firewall.  I don't think this will help, since you're connecting to port 3000, but it might be that you're running a proxy on port 3000 that needs to connect to port 443.

Instead of opening that port I would suggest disabling your firewall and retrying that.  If it works, then you should look into making an exception for that port.  Here's how to disable the firewall:  (Which will open that port)

**Open System Preferences->Security->Firewall and click "Stop".**  Don't forget to turn it back on when you're done testing.